# Getting could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432

Tags: windows, postgresql

I have Postgres 13 and pgAdmin installed on my Windows machine. It worked for like ~six month, until I hat do restart my machine. After restarting the computer (which I had not *done* because there was an update), I am trying to connect to Postgres via pgAdmin as always and I get this

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Some answeres suggest, to edit the `postgresql.conf` file which I a) do not find in my postgres installation and b) I think is not the correct solution for me because it worked without any problem until I restarted my machine.

Why is that? It feels like postgres is not starting? Although this is a wild guess...
I went to `Control Panel->Administrator Tools->Services` and found out Postgres' service name which is `postgresql-x64-13 - PostgreSQL Server 13`. When I try

```
runas /user:Administrator cmd
```

and then

```
net start postgresql-x64-13 - PostgreSQL Server 13
```

I get

System Error 5. Access Denied.

This is driving me nuts...

Comment: The error says it all already: it appears that your Postgres database server has not been started, which is why you can't connect from pgAdmin. You may want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629963/how-can-i-start-postgresql-on-windows - maybe start with `net start postgresql-x64-13`

Comment: Use "run as" but that is the limit of my Windows knowledge

Comment: Ahhh. finally. Type `services.msc`, let the Pop Up open and search for `Postgres` there. Then, start/top the service there. Make sure to restart `pgAdmin` after doing this...

Answer (score 2):

As Rob pointed out (and as I assumed): Postgres database server has not been started (yet).

To start it manually type `services.msc` in i.e. 'PowerShell`, let the Pop Up open and search for Postgres there. Then, start/top the service there. Make sure to restart pgAdmin after doing this...